# Setting "src" attribute for html5 player in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have tried with the following factors for setting the **src** attribute for my html5 video player in i.e.,

```
 $("#vid").attr("src","video.mp4");

  $("#vid").setAttribute("src","video.mp4");

  $("#vid").prop("src","video.mp4");
```

i have searched in many forums that `attr()` is not working in ie browser and they are giving alternate solution as

use `val()` function for setting the value for the particular tag.

use `$("#div").id = "value"` for some of the attribute like `id`,`class` and some `events`  like `click`.

But i could not find the solution for changing the `src` of the particular `video` or `image`. please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Which IE version? below IE 11 it doesn't work, you'll need to use flash objects to play video's...

Comment: IE 9 it is not working

Comment: have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942619/javascript-with-html-video-load-play-function-not-firing

Comment: "src" only not loading in my video tag. Not a video loading problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use native DOM attributes, you need to get the DOM element (not a jQuery collection):

```
document.getElementById('vid').src = 'video.mp4';
```

Or:

```
$('#vid').get(0).src = 'video.mp4'
```

But I’m guessing that this is not where the IE problem lies, make sure the browser supports HTML5 video at all.

If you are using a flash replacement for IE, you will not be able to change the src attrbute at runtime. You will have to replace the entire flash container.

Answer (score 0):

so let us say that you have the following HTML code:

```
 <video id="vid" width="320" height="240" controls>
    <!-- You might do different for browser compatibility. -->
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="" type="video/ogg">
 </video>
```

Now what we need to do is to first grap the video tag by its id [vid] and then loop through each source while changing their src. Like so:

```
$(function(){
  var myExt  = new Array();
  myExt[0]   = "mp4";
  myExt[1]   = "ogg";
  var extCounter = 0;

  $("#vid").children("source").each(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < myExt.length; i++){
        $(this).attr("src","http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny"+"."+myExt[extCounter]);
    }
    extCounter++;
  });
});
```

[Click here for codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JHtgF)

p.s Check if your browsers supports it.. We are talking about ie here..