# video .load() Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

Under jQuery 2.2.4, the below code was working. But after switching over to Bootstrap 4 and jQuery 3.5.1, it stopped working and I saw the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

I was able to determine that the error was happening at the moment of attempting to use the `load()` method on the `<video>` container - but the container exists (`el.length() == 1`) and literally nothing else changed other than jQuery/Bootstrap.

HTML:

```
    <div class="vlink"><div class="vid" id="bl">[ Video 1 ]</div></div>
    <div class="vlink"><div class="vid" id="bg">[ Video 2 ]</div></div>

    <div id="lb" class="absoluteDiv flex-parent">
        <div id="inner" class="flex-parent">
            <div id="closex"> &times; </div>
            <div id="lbBody">
                <div id="videoDiv">
                    <video id="video" width="700" controls><source id="vidsource" src="" type="video/mp4"></video>
                </div>
                <div id="explan"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript/jQuery:

```
    let id = this.id;
    $('#vidsource').attr('src', './vid/'+id+'.mp4');
    $('#video').load().attr('autoplay', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Under Bootstrap4 / jQuery 3.5.1, it is necessary to set the src attribute on the `<video>` container itself (just totally ignore the `<source>` element.

Also, use attributes on the `<video>` container to force play:

```
let id = this.id;
$('#video').attr('src', './vid/'+id+'.mp4').attr('autoplay', true);
```

There is one report that this has something to do with the files being referenced in nested tags, specifically in webkit browsers.

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7993347